# PHP Implode get expected result for IN query

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me How can I get my expected result and thanks in advance plus sorry for my weak English.

PHP:

```
  $dog = implode(',', $data['dogbreed']);
  $query .= "AND `dog_breeds`.`id` IN ('".$dog."')";
```

OUTPUT:

```
AND `dog_breeds`.`id` IN ('9,31')
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
AND `dog_breeds`.`id` IN ('9','31')
```

Array:

```
([0] => 9 [1] => 31)
```

Comment: Of course, you should really be using parametrised queries, which in the case of IN() are rather tricky things to construct. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line:-

```
$dog = implode(',', $data['dogbreed']);
```

to:-

```
$dog = implode("','", $data['dogbreed']);
```

And your code will work fine.(***don't change anything else***)

Check output here:- https://eval.in/784234

Note:-

**Please don't change this line**:-

```
$query .= "AND `dog_breeds`.`id` IN ('".$dog."')";
```

Comment: @shahrushabh, please pay attention. You *must* put the extra quotes in the first argument of  `implode`. Don't waste people's time by trying with code that is not exactly as provided to you.

Comment: @shahrushabh  please read my answer properly. and you will get the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
$dog = implode("','", $data['dogbreed']);
$query .= "AND `dog_breeds`.`id` IN ('".$dog."')";
```

Comment: Remove that ```.``` which exist before ```=```.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change. Try this

```
$data['dogbreed']   =   array(9,10);
$dog = implode('","', $data['dogbreed']);
print  $query = 'AND dog_breeds.id IN ("'.$dog.'")';
```